# Cashing a foreign check in US

Tags: united-states, india, check

Is it possible to deposit a check issued by a foreign bank in a US bank?

To be specific, I would like to know if I can deposit a check issued by a bank in India in INR in my bank in US. I was able to do the reverse, that is, cash a USD check from BofA in my bank in India.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is definately possible to deposit a Foreign currency check in US. On most currencies like CAD or GBP it would be very simple and easy.

On INR as littleadv pointed out its up to the Bank.
Technically the Bank's can do it, however there needs to be enough volume to justify or support this. Typically the checks are sent over to India via a correspondant Bank, then once the check is encashed in India, the funds are converted and credited into your USD account. Typically the entire process takes around 4-5 weeks and has quite a few manual intervention steps.

You can encash USD checks in India, and they follow the same process of sending the check to US, getting the funds and then crediting the funds into your account. As the volume of USD checks getting encashed in India is high, most the Banks in India would offer the service. However if you try to encash say a Chinese Yuan or Indonesian Rupiya check in India, you will not find Indian Bankers encashing the same.

So the best way to get money moved from India to US would be to buy a Bankers check denominated in USD in India and take it along to US. Alternatively initiate a Wire/SWIFT from India to transfer funds to US account. Note most banks in India do not allow an online mechanism to Initiate a Wire out of India and one has to visit the Branch to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to the bank, they can either do that or not. Indian currency is not in the CLS list, which makes it more troublesome to buy and sell.

You should try going into banks in areas with large Indian population (the Bay Area, NYC) and ask. Most banks won't cash such a check, and if you find one that does - expect high fees and long delays.

Cashing a USD check is easy more or less anywhere in the world, it doesn't mean that cashing a local currency check in the US should be as easy.

Cashing check drawn on a foreign bank but in USD is easier, although also not as simple as cashing a domestic check (there are fees and delays). You might want to consider converting the check from INR to USD in India before coming to the US.